# How to configure http request to listen to java service for new data

Tags: angular, http, watchservice

I'm working on a spring web app in which I have a rest controller that watches a directory for new files (which works fine) but it is supposed to send a string to the client side each time it detects a new document
My question is how get the data automaticly from the server every time
I'm using angular by the way
any help, please!